# How to set $userID from queried object ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I am editing a template to try and add some conditional logic to my page.

The page template shows topics related to a user.

I want to add a piece of code which will grab the user name from the page we are viewing and then use that in a string for my conditional statements.

The code I have put together is as follows, but it breaks my page so I am doing something wrong.

```
<?php global
// I query the ID and try and set that to the $userID - I think I am doing this  wrong, but when I echo the ID it gets the correct info.
$userID = get_queried_object()->ID; 
// This is the string I create using the userID which should be from the query above
$memberstatus = get_user_meta($userID,'member_status',true); 

 ?>
```

later on I use IF statements to use thsi result (which i know work) so i won't post them. My problem is trying to get the above to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damm, looks like when I remove 'global' from the php it works! I thought global had to be in this...ah well

Comment: Remember to turn on error reporting (and display errors) so you can **see** the errors that come up.